# When adding 1 to the index, at the point where I > array.length, undefined is returned. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing

Currently, im adding 1 to the index on click, to simulate a user controlled iteration of the array. I have a conditional statement where if i > length, i = 0; Yet im still getting undefined after reaching the end of the array.

```
    const marqueeMonthlies = () => {
        intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            insertMarquee.empty('');
            // i %= marqueeMonthlyPlates.length
            insertMarquee.append(
                `<div class="container" id="generatedMonthlyPlates">
                <input type="text" width="100px" name="monthlyLicensePlate" id="${marqueeMonthlyPlates[i]}" class="licensePlate" placeholder="AB12345" value="${marqueeMonthlyPlates[i]}"/>
                </div>`
            )
            // i++;     
        }, 5000);
    }

    const getNextMonthly = () => {
        if ( i < marqueeMonthlyPlates.length) {
            i = i+1
            return marqueeMonthlyPlates[i]    
        } else
        if (i > marqueeMonthlyPlates.length){
            i = 0;
            return marqueeMonthlyPlates[i];
        } else 
        if (marqueeMonthlyPlates.length === undefined ){
            i = 0;
            return marqueeMonthlyPlates[i];
        }
        
    }
```

I tried to catch for when undefined present, to set the index back to 0, but it only corrects itself when 1 is added to i again on another click. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: indexes are 0-based. Try `length-1`

Comment: FYI, `x.empty(); x.append(contents)` is the same as `x.html(contents)`

Comment: `length` will never be undefined.

Comment: Use `>=`, not `>`. Because there is no entry at `theArray[theArray.length]`, the valid indexes are `0` through `theArray.length - 1`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, so you're saying when i >= array.length {array.length -1 i=0}?

Comment: @Barmar, i comes back undefined when i > array.length. which I believed my if statement to correct that but thats not the case sadly

Comment: @BlakeT - I don't understand that question, but `if (i > marqueeMonthlyPlates.length){ i = 0; ...` is incorrect if the goal is to wrap `i` back to `0` when you reach the end. It should be `>=`, not `>`.

Comment: @BlakeT That shouldn't happen. `array[i]` will be undefined, but `array.length` won't be.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, my apologies I was misunderstanding your original comment. changing `>`, to `>=` didnt work for me at first, but I removed the initial if statement for checking when `i < array.length, i = i+1`, to just check for when `i >= array.length, i = 0`. as when this event is triggered, i always = 0;

Comment: @Barmar, you're right, my question wasn't articulated properly.

Answer (score -1):

The answer was to change my greater than statement, as the goal was to bring i back to 0 when it reached the end.

```
        if (i > marqueeMonthlyPlates.length){
            i = 0;
            return marqueeMonthlyPlates[i];
```

to

```
        if (i >= marqueeMonthlyPlates.length){
            i = 0;
            return marqueeMonthlyPlates[i];
```